# Can I checkout branch from local git mirror clone

Tags: git, git-mirror

I have cloned my repo using `--mirror` flag, can I checkout branch from it if yes how? if no why ?

`git branch` shows me list of all branches but `git checkout branch-name` gives me error saying:
`fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: A bare repository does not have a work tree, it only contains the commits and the history of the repository, not a place for you to edit the files. As such, operations such as "check out" won't work unless you do a non-bare clone, either from the original source or from your bare repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the official [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror):

> `--mirror`
>
> Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies `--bare`. Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only maps local branches of the source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs
> (including remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec
> configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a `git remote update` in the target repository.

Cloning with the `--mirror` option you are implicitly using the `--bare` option, which create a repository without a working tree.
The `--bare` option is used mainly at server-side or in specific use cases.

In your case you shouldn't directly use your mirrored repo, as not having a working tree, is not suitable for editing files or for git commands as `git checkout`.
You should `git clone your-mirrored-repo` (without the `--bare`/`--mirror` option) to have a full working tree, started from the mirrored repo, in which you can use all the git commands or edit files directly.